# How do you save a model, dictionary and corpus to disk in Gensim, and then load them again?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

In Gensim's [documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/core/run_core_concepts.html), it says:

> You can save trained models to disk and later load them back, either to continue training on new training documents or to transform new documents.

I would like to do this with a dictionary, corpus and tf.idf model. However, the documentation seems to say that it is possible, without explaining how to save these things and load them back up again.

How do you do this?

---

I've been using Pickle, but don't know if this is right...

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(tfidf, open("tfidf.p", "wb"))
tfidf_reloaded = pickle.load(open("tfidf.p", "rb"))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you can save things with generic Python `pickle`, but most `gensim` models support their own native `.save()` method.

It takes a target filesystem path, and will save the model more efficiently than `pickle()` – often by placing large component arrays in separate files, alongside the main file. (When you later move the saved model, keep all these files with the same root name together.)

In particular, some models which have multi-gigabyte subcomponents may not save at all with `pickle()` – but `gensim`'s native `.save()` will work.

Models saved with `.save()` can typically be loaded by using the appropriate class's `.load()` method. (For example if you've saved a instance of `gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary`, you'd load it with `gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary.load(filepath)`.

Comment: Up! :) Tf-idf transformator is typically smaller when saved with gensim's native save method.

Answer (score 6):

Saving the Dict and Corpus to disk

```
dictionary.save(DICT_PATH)
corpora.MmCorpus.serialize(CORPUS_PATH, corpus)
```

Loading the Dict and Corpus from disk

```
loaded_dict = corpora.Dictionary.load(DICT_PATH)
loaded_corp = corpora.MmCorpus(CORPUS_PATH)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python default [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) should save all python object. As an example

```py
import pickle

file_name = 'myModel.sav'
pickle.dump(my_model, open(fime_name, 'wb'))
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(file_name, 'rb))
```